# Forbid spring boot add a filter with @Bean to filterchain

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I create a filter for shiro, use `@Bean`, but spring boot add it to servlet filterchain.

I used it in shiro filterChainDefinitions:

```
shiroFilterFactoryBean.getFilters().put("apiValid", getApiValidFilter()); 

@Bean(name = "apiValid") 
public ApiValidFilter getApiValidFilter() { 
    return new ApiValidFilter(); 
}
```

I want the filter as a spring bean, to get benefit from spring, like use `@Autowired`, but do not want it add to filterchain automatic.

How to config spring boot to pervent this behavior?

Comment: Then how are you going to add it to the filter chain? A filter without being added is pretty much useless.

Comment: Please don't add code blocks as comments, improve your question with it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-disable-registration-of-a-servlet-or-filter), you can create a `FilterRegistrationBean` for the `Filter` and mark it as disabled:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration(MyFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works.
I want to know, how spring boot add @Bean filter to filter chain automatic?