# Spring MVC Controller: too (fat) much going on?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am not quite sure if it is okay to ask such questions in here, but I ran into a problem of my Spring MVC controllers, to my opinion, becoming too fat.

Here is a sample of one:

```
@GetMapping("/firms/firm/{id}")
    public String getFirmById (@PathVariable String id,
                               Map <String, Object> model,
                               HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                               HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
                               HttpSession httpSession) throws IOException {

        log.info("Getting data for firm with id {}", id);
        model.put(VERSION, applicationVersion);
        Cookie cookie = authService.findCookie(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = authService.createJwtAuthHeader(cookie);
        HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
        ResponseEntity <UserObject> userObjectResponse = authService.createUserResponseEntity(requestEntity, servletResponse);
        authService.setUserSessionDetails(userObjectResponse, httpSession);

        if (userObjectResponse != null && userObjectResponse.getBody() != null) {
            log.info(CommonMessages.GOT_COOKIE_FROM_AUTH_SERVICE.toString(), cookie.getName());
            servletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            ResponseEntity <Firm> firmResponse = restTemplate.exchange(urlApiFirms + id,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    requestEntity,
                    Firm.class);
            model.put("firm", firmResponse.getBody());
            return "firm";
        } else {
            log.error(CommonMessages.NO_COOKIES_FOUND_NO_ACCESS_REDIRECTING.toString());
            servletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            httpSession.setAttribute("authorized", false);
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

Each controller starts with a security check, which is a requirement for this application. I was thinking I can move code starting from `Cookie cookie = authService.findCookie(servletRequest, servletResponse);` until and including `authService.setUserSessionDetails(userObjectResponse, httpSession);` into a separate service in order to remove duplicate code.

But I am still left with requirements to fill Thymeleaf `model` with values, which I can also do from other Services. But that would make my controller call many more services, which I am not sure is the correct way to go.

Am I moving into the correct direction with my thinking or am I totally off?
Thanks!

Comment: You should use Spring Security for this matters. That is a whole framework taking away all these tasks from you. [Have a read in their docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web).

Comment: usually a good mapping is just "/firms/{id}", also usually security should not be a part of controller logic; if it is Spring - couldn't you add Spring security ?

Comment: You can use a servlet filter to do the security check so possibly avoid the duplication of code.

Comment: @john I fully agree about Spring Security. But unfortunately I didn't figure out a way to implement Spring Cloud Security into my Thymeleaf UI client app. I have a separate Auth Service which is utilizing Spring Cloud Security, JWT and issuing tokens upon rest request and is being request through a ZUUL gateway...

Comment: @ajithgeorge can you share an example, please?

Comment: @DenissM. Have you tried this https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity ? Maybe it can be useful.

Comment: @john I've seen that example. My problem is a bit earlier in the process. I do not know how to tell my UI client service (if it were to use Spring Cloud Security) that it is doing its security operations through a separate Authorization token service.

Comment: @DenissM if you have deployment descriptior add something like `<filter>
  <filter-name>testFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>testFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/test/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>`
and create a filter class by extending the GenericFilterBean do the logic there.

Comment: @ajithgeorge I don't do any config in xml :) just Java.

Comment: These answers might help -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239809/forbid-spring-boot-add-a-filter-with-bean-to-filterchain, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243381/how-to-set-up-filter-chain-in-spring-boot